Brother QL-800 on Ubuntu not recognised
I'm trying to use a Brother QL-800 label printer on Kubuntu. I successfully manged to use a QL-600 but struggling with QL-800. I installed the driver package ql800pdrv-3.1.5-0.i386.deb which I downloaded from brother website.
At http://localhost:631/printers/ there is now showing a QL-800 printer. But when I try to print a test page, it sais "Wait for the printer to become available".
In the systems printer settings under connection there is an entry with "usb://dev/usb/lp0"
I compared to my QL-600 printer, which is set to something like "usb://Brother/QL-600?serial=XXXXXXXXX" - so I wonder if this might be the problem?
Besides my laptop I also failed to get it to work on a Raspberry Pi 5 with Ubuntu. But there I already fail installing the ARM drivers from Brother website.
